# Jquery Datatables and Bootstrap Toggle Doesn't work Together

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

i'm using datatables from : https://www.datatables.net/

and also i'm using Bootstrap Toggle from : http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Here is my code :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="table-list-tour">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Featured</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($packages as $package) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="shownCheckbox" id="<?php echo $package->id ?>" data-toggle="toggle">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>

<Script>
  $('#table-list-tour').DataTable();

  $(".toggle-group").click(function(){
    var selectedCheckBox = $(this);

    var id        = selectedCheckBox.parent().children('input').attr('id');
    var isChecked = selectedCheckBox.is(':checked');

    $.ajax({
      url         : 'A_LINK',
      type        : 'post',
      data        : {'id':id},
      success:function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
        if (isChecked && data !== '') {
          selectedCheckBox.attr('checked', false);
          alert(data);
        }
      },
      error:function()
      {
        alert('Toggle Failed !');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The problem is, in page 1, the AJAX in bootstrap toggle event works perfectly, when i move to page 2, all the ajax did not work at all,
why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Pages other than first do not exist in DOM at the time of initialization, that is why your handler never gets called.

#### SOLUTION

You need to use event delegation by providing selector as a second argument in [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call, see example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table-list-tour').DataTable();

    $('#table-list-tour').on('click', '.toggle-group', function(){
        // ... skipped ...
    });   
});
```

From jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
> descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

See "Direct and delegated events" in jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation and [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.

Comment: Ah ~, Thanks for the solution. Kinda new to Jquery, i search for click function on google and it just return click(). Anyway, thanks for the solution